# Lightning: Cause of error code 87F10B8A (-2014246006)

Tags: lightning

I'm getting an Internal Server Error returning data from my controller method to my lightning component. I get an unhelpful Aura stacktrace.

`Error: An internal server error has occurred
Error ID: 2064214854-110002 (-2014246006)
    at AuraClientService.$processErrors$ (https://my-domain.na40.force.com/s/sfsites/auraFW/javascript/ZCuyRUYzK_kAf4cKCIeS2A/aura_proddebug.js:11861:19)
    at AuraClientService.$receive$ (https://my-domain.na40.force.com/s/sfsites/auraFW/javascript/ZCuyRUYzK_kAf4cKCIeS2A/aura_proddebug.js:11837:16)
    at Object.onXHRReceived (https://my-domain.na40.force.com/components/instrumentation/beacon.js:133:32)
    at Object.Aura.$Utils$.$Override$.$continuation$ (https://my-domain.na40.force.com/s/sfsites/auraFW/javascript/ZCuyRUYzK_kAf4cKCIeS2A/aura_proddebug.js:4315:20)
    at TransportMetricsPlugin.$receiveOverride$ (https://my-domain.na40.force.com/s/sfsites/auraFW/javascript/ZCuyRUYzK_kAf4cKCIeS2A/aura_proddebug.js:20192:23)
    at Object.Aura.$Utils$.$Override$.$continuation$ (https://my-domain.na40.force.com/s/sfsites/auraFW/javascript/ZCuyRUYzK_kAf4cKCIeS2A/aura_proddebug.js:4315:20)
    at Override.Aura.$Utils$.$Override$.start (https://my-domain.na40.force.com/s/sfsites/auraFW/javascript/ZCuyRUYzK_kAf4cKCIeS2A/aura_proddebug.js:4293:30)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onReady (https://my-domain.na40.force.com/s/sfsites/auraFW/javascript/ZCuyRUYzK_kAf4cKCIeS2A/aura_proddebug.js:11679:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (https://my-domain.na40.force.com/s/sfsites/auraFW/javascript/ZCuyRUYzK_kAf4cKCIeS2A/aura_proddebug.js:18734:23)`

But that error looks like an error HResult. Google netted me no results, but wondering if anyone has ever seen error codes that SFDC/Lightning can throw.

I'm nearly certain that the error is not being thrown by my controller method. When I force an NPE in the controller, Aura gives me the message "Tried to reference a Null Pointer" w/ no stack trace. That is not what I'm getting here.

I have a strong suspicion that the failure is in JSON serialization, but I'd like some more data, if possible.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Answer (score 2):

I re-arranged my code and believe I triggered the error in my controller. Turns out I had a circular reference in my object graph and the JSON serializer was barfing.

So $1 says that 87F10B8A is a circular reference or a more general JSON serializer error.